# Avermedia AverTV Volar HD 2 Model TD110

Tags: tv, tv-tuner, v4l

recently I bought this card, and there is no way to have it working in Linux Mint. Looking at the windows inf file, looks like the card uses the IT9135 driver

```
[Strings]
AVERMEDIA                   = "AVerMedia TECHNOLOGIES, Inc"
AVerIT13x.CLSID           = "{17CCA71B-ECD7-11D0-B908-00A0C9223196}"
AVerIT13x.Disc            = "AVerMedia DVB-T BDA Driver Installation Disc"
AVerIT13x.DeviceDesc      = "AVerTV Volar HD 2"
AVerIT13x.DeviceFriendlyName = "AVerTV Volar HD 2"
AVerIT13x.FriendlyName    = "IT9135 BDA Filter"
KSNAME_Filter           = "{CACACEFD-1B5F-49f4-AF24-0CE559CC1E6D}"

Plugin_BdaDevice        = "BDA Device Control Plug-in"
GUID.TunerCatID         = "{71985F48-1CA1-11d3-9CC8-00C04F7971E0}"
AMcatID                 = "{DA4E3DA0-D07D-11d0-BD50-00A0C911CE86}"
BDAReceivers            = "BDA Streaming Receiver Components"
MediaCategories         = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\MediaCategories"
Pin.BdaTransport        = "BDA Transport Stream"
GUID.BdaTransport       = "{78216A81-CFA8-493e-9711-36A61C08BD9D}"
GUID.BdaReceiverCtrl    = "{FD0A5AF4-B41D-11d2-9C95-00C04F7971E0}"
```

I compiled the media_build v4l, nothing

Thats a lsusb result

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 07ca:a110 AVerMedia Technologies, Inc
```

Nothing shows regarding DVB when I do a dmesg | grep DVB

Just this appears in dmesg

```
[ 1090.183117] usb 3-4: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 1097.452769] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 1097.473774] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=07ca, idProduct=a110
[ 1097.473785] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1097.473791] usb 3-2: Product: TD110
[ 1097.473796] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: AVerMedia TECHNOLOGIES, Inc.7
[ 1097.473801] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 20055820068
```

I tried with the IT9135 firmwares I found, nothing, also the Afatech ones, nothing as well.

May someone have an idea on how to get this device working under UBUNTU/Linux Mint?

Thanks